# Change SRC on click of a link.. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click, src

I'm currently creating some kind of slideshow.. It's just a floorplan, so it shouldnt be neat looking. I'm using link numbers to specify floors. When clicked on one of the links, the corresponding floor image will be shown.

Below the code I currently have.. but the src of the image doesn't change on click. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
        <div id="bovengedeelte">
        <img src="image1.png" id="plattegrond" width="300" height="300" alt="plattegrond" />
        </div>

        <div id="ondergedeelte">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("a.floor0").click(function(event){
          $("img.plattegrond").attr("src","floor0.png");
        });
            $("a.floor1").click(function(event){
          $("img.plattegrond").attr("src","floor1.png");
        });     
            $("a.floor2").click(function(event){
          $("img.plattegrond").attr("src","floor2.png");
        });     
        $("a.floor3").click(function(event){
          $("img.plattegrond").attr("src","floor3.png");
        });         
        $("a.floor4").click(function(event){
          $("img.plattegrond").attr("src","floor4.png");
        });         
        $("a.floor5").click(function(event){
          $("img.plattegrond").attr("src","floor5.png");
        });         </script>
        <p>Kies een verdieping</p>
        <a id="floor0" href="#">0</a><a id="floor1" href="#">1</a><a id="floor2" href="#">2</a><a id="floor3" href="#">3</a><a id="floor4" href="#">4</a><a id="floor5" href="#">5</a>
        </div>
```

**to everyone: It's still not working after all your solutions. Thanks already! Can someone check the whole code and see what i'm doing wrong? :s

```
http://prototyping.iscs.nl/
```

**

Comment: Because you are using a.floor1 and it should be a#floor1, etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this:

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WDx8p/)**

```
    <div id="bovengedeelte">
          <img src="image1.png" id="plattegrond" width="300" height="300" alt="plattegrond" />
    </div>

    <div id="ondergedeelte">

        <p>Kies een verdieping</p>
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>

    </div>
```

jQ:

```
$(function(){ // document ready shorthand

    $('#ondergedeelte a').click(function( e ){
         e.preventDefault();
         var newImgUrl = 'floor'+ $(this).text() +'.png' ;
         $('#plattegrond').attr('src', newImgUrl );
    });

});
```

Comment: that's the most robust solution out of the three. Really nice!

Comment: Just copied it over to my code.. Somehow it is still not working. Can you check out what i'm doing wrong? Check the URL link in the OP and check the source code please. P.s. The code looks really neat and clean. And the fiddle is working too, so I don't see why mine isn't. :s

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer edited my code: you need to wrap it into a document ready as I did

Answer (score 1):

So you're not correctly searching for `a` with `class` instead of what you have an `id`. This will work:

```
$("a#floor5").click(function(event) {
    $("img#plattegrond").attr("src","floor5.png");
});
```

@Jay Blanchard in the comments is totally right.

Also, a good way to debug and see if you found the right element is to do a `console.log` with your jQuery object like so: `console.log($("a#floor5"));` if it does print out the element you're looking for, then you're fine to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a class in your jQuery selector instead of an id. Additionally you can shorten your jQuery code like this -

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisNumber = id.substr(id.length - 1);
    $('img#plattergrond').attr('src', 'floor' + thisNumber + '.png');
});
```

Now no matter how many links or images added they will be handled properly.

Comment: you missed that his `img` also is defined with the `id` property. Also, what happens if he has more than one `a` on his page I.e not just the ones intended to change images? Something more robust would be needed :)

Comment: Absolutely Morgan - his links for the photos should have a class applied to them.

Comment: I can't get your code working.. :s already changed
    $('img.plattergrond')attr
to
    $('img #plattergrond')attr

Comment: Dreamweaver keeps telling me there is a syntax  error on the following line "$('img#plattergrond')attr('src', 'floor' + thisNumber + '.png');" and besides that.. Even after your change (which is same as I did.. it's still not working.

I do have the jquery.js linked via Google lib

Comment: Jay, already thank you for your help. Your code looks neat and clean, yet, it is still not working. Could you please open the link in the OP, where I posted the URL where the code is stored and check the whole code and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your images in the web root folder? I could not access by going to http://prototyping.iscs.nl/floor1.png for example. I can see in Firefox that the src attribute is changing when I click the numbers, so the code is working.